# Getting dynamic control values inside a dynamically created table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I am trying to read my checkbox values in my table cells, however while doing a postback via button submit, the entire table disappears. I only create the table if it's not a postback when a page_load occurs and I thought the table would persist across postback once created.

How do I retain the entire table with its cell's checkboxes values? Thanks.

```
protected void CreateTable()
{
    int rowCnt; // Total number of rows.
    int rowCtr; // Current row count.
    int cellCtr; // Total number of cells per row (columns).
    int cellCnt; // Current cell counter.

    rowCnt = 6;
    cellCnt = 8;

    string baseStartTime = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DEFAULTBASESELLSCHEDULETIME"]);
    int incrementInMins = Convert.ToInt32((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DEFAULTBASESELLSCHEDULETIME_INCREMENT"]));

    DateTime tempTimeFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(baseStartTime); // Converts only the time
    tempTimeFrom = tempTimeFrom.AddMinutes(-incrementInMins);
    // Because the very first loop will add 30 mins right away 

    for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
    {
        tempTimeFrom = tempTimeFrom.AddMinutes(incrementInMins);
        DateTime tempTimeTo = tempTimeFrom.AddMinutes(incrementInMins);

        string timeFrom = tempTimeFrom.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        string timeToClassName = tempTimeTo.ToString("hh:mm");
        string timeTo = tempTimeTo.ToString("hh:mm tt");

        // Create a new row and add it to the table.
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
        tblSellSchedule.Rows.Add(tRow);
        for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

            if (cellCtr == 1) // We need the time for the first column of every row
            {
                tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(timeFrom + "-" + timeTo));
                tCell.CssClass = timeToClassName;
            }
            else
            {
                // tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Select"));
                CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox();

                chkbox.ID = tblSellSchedule.Rows[rowCtr - 1].Cells[0].CssClass + (cellCtr - 1);
                tCell.Controls.Add(chkbox);
                //  tCell.ID = (cellCtr - 1).ToString();
                tCell.CssClass = (cellCtr - 1).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableRow row in tblSellSchedule.Rows)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            foreach (CheckBox c in cell.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {
                if (c.Checked)
                {
                    var idVal = c.ID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        CreateTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should call your method CreateTable() in page_Init().
because on every post back every DOM content you have created will be vanished. so you have to create it again on every post back, so you have to do this recreation in page_Init() that is accessed before page_Load().